# Automatic merge after tests pass using Actions?

Tags: git, github, automation, github-actions, git-merge

I was wondering whether it's possible to automate merging of branches after tests pass using GitHub Actions.

We have two branches, 'test' and 'main'. After every merge or push to 'test', we have a Workflow set up to run tests.

Is it possible to make GitHub automatically merge 'test' -> 'main' after the tests complete, and only if they complete successfully?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to do the following:

1. Enable auto-merge for your repository, see the Github documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/automatically-merging-a-pull-request)
2. Go to the branch protection rules of your repository. To get there:

   1. Go to your repos settings
   2. Go to "branches" in the section "Code and automation"
3. Add or edit the branch protection rules for the branch you want to merge your pull requests into, so e.g. `main` or `master`
4. Activate "Require status checks to pass before merging"
5. Type each name of your (Github Actions) workflows into the free text field with the description "Search for status checks in the last week of this repository"

Then auto-merging should be possible. I just did it today e.g. [here](https://github.com/flyingdutchman23/watson-overtime/pull/7).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Though I'm a bit lost on the 4-5th step. I typed my Workflow name into the field but it didn't come up with any suggestions, as if it didn't see my workflow. Any idea why this may be? Even typing out "Search for status ...." does nothing to find them.

Comment: No, sorry, I do not, but is your repository public? If yes, could you add a link to your question? Then I can have a look.

Comment: I figured it out. You have to give your workflows names in the `.yml` itself it seems to find them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JackAvante I have the same problem, when i type the name of the workflow it does not display. How did you solve it?

Comment: Here is a screenshot for my `.yml` file https://ibb.co/KXJ1pNm

Comment: I solved it, i should have typed the job name, which is in my case `build_and_preview`.

Comment: This answer only talks about auto-merging pull requests, while the original question was about auto-merging a branch after it passes CI, with no pull requests involved.

Comment: @AndreySemashev I think with GitHub, pull requests are almost assumed implicitly. It's necessary to be explicit that the question is not about PRs. The question does not state that explicitly, and as the asker accepted this answer, I think it's fair to say the original question was about pull requests implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I run an app, [Mergery](https://github.com/apps/mergery), that does this for pull requests. Because it's an app, not an Action, it runs independently of actions so is able to ensure all the actions have passed and the merge button is green before merging.